# How can I connect public and private node through a reverse SSH tunnel?

Tags: node, p2p

I have set up my baker with:

- a public non-baking node with public IP, let's call it "A.A.A.A"
- a private baking node without public IP

To lock down the private node (and also because it does not need a public IP), I have set up a [reverse SSH tunnel](https://cnly.github.io/2018/08/16/setting-up-autossh-to-maintain-a-reverse-tunnel-ssh-server-having-a-dynamic-ip-address.html) for port 9732 from the private to the public node on 19732. Thus, the public node can connect to the private node via its own 127.0.0.1:19732, which forwards to the private nodes port 9732.

I'm running the private node with: `./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --private-mode --no-bootstrap-peers --bootstrap-threshold=1 --connections 1 --peer A.A.A.A`

And I'm running the public node with: `./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --peer 127.0.0.1:19732`

Additionally, I have tried adding different `trust` entries like:

- `./tezos-admin-client trust address 127.0.0.1:19732` on public node
- `./tezos-admin-client trust address A.A.A.A:9732` on private node
- `./tezos-admin-client trust peer idxxxxxx` on both private and public node

All I keep getting in the private nodes log is: `p2p.connection-pool: [private node] incoming connection from untrused peer rejected!` and the public node tries, but can never successfully connect to the private node or the other way around.

What can I do or check to get closer to connecting my nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same exact situation.  It seems that (and I did not see this documented anywhere) when using private mode, the private node must initiate the connection.  In my case it was a firewall rule preventing the private node from establishing the connection, and after I permitted that everything worked great.

Comment: Holy smokes, you where right! Doing a `sudo ufw allow out from any` and connecting from the private node solved it.